# Conjecture: The line joining the incenter and the circumcenter always subtends an obtuse angle at centroid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, maxima-minima, triangle-inequality

Consider the triangle formed by joining the circumcenter, the incenter and the centroid of a triangle (is there is already a name for this triangle in literature?). Simulations show that the line joining the incenter and the circumcenter always subtends and obtuse angle at centroid (except when the triangle is degenerate).

[image]

> **Conjecture**: In any triangle, the line joining the incenter and the circumcenter always subtends and obtuse angle at centroid.

Can this be proved or disproved?

Comment: Take a look to [Euler line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line), then define what you call _"when the triangle is degenerate"_.